# Tensorflow object detection api v1 object detection api mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco slow inference and memory leak

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-segmentation, object-detection-api

I am trying to use mask rcnn model (mask_rcnn_inception_v2_coco) from [tensorflow object detection api](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md#coco-trained-models) (v1).
I tried to inference a video using the following two methods.
(These two methods are similar to methods provided in TensorFlow object detection API notebooks)

I faced two problems.

1. Inference speed is slower than the values mentioned in the model
   zoo.

The inference is about 40x slower, this is definitely cannot be explained by the difference between 2 GPUS.
(Tensorflow had used Nvidia GeForce GTX TITAN X and mine is GTX 1660 ti (laptop))

2. Memory usage gradually increases. (especially for method 2, this increment is significant) (possible memory leak?)

(The video I took was a very small one 2sec (60 frames,1280x720 ))

- Model zoo: 0.079 sec
- My methord_1: 3.2864 sec
- My methord_2: 3.1711 sec

**Memory Usage and inference time**

- methord 1 -> (2640M to 2840M)  3.4047 sec
- methord 2 -> (2640M to 4220M)  3.3096 sec

**methord 1**

```
def run_inference_1(cap):
    while cap.isOpened():
        with detection_graph.as_default():
            with tf.Session() as sess:
                
                ret, image_np = cap.read()
                if(ret==False):
                    break
                # Get handles to input and output tensors
                ops = tf.get_default_graph().get_operations()
                all_tensor_names = {output.name for op in ops for output in op.outputs}
                tensor_dict = {}
                for key in [
                    'num_detections', 'detection_boxes', 'detection_scores',
                    'detection_classes', 'detection_masks']:
                    tensor_name = key + ':0'

                    if tensor_name in all_tensor_names:
                        tensor_dict[key] = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name(tensor_name)
                if 'detection_masks' in tensor_dict:
                    # The following processing is only for single image
                    detection_boxes = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_boxes'], [0])
                    detection_masks = tf.squeeze(tensor_dict['detection_masks'], [0])
                    # Reframe is required to translate mask from box coordinates to image coordinates and fit the image size.
                    real_num_detection = tf.cast(tensor_dict['num_detections'][0], tf.int32)
                    
                    detection_boxes = tf.slice(detection_boxes, [0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1])
                    detection_masks = tf.slice(detection_masks, [0, 0, 0], [real_num_detection, -1, -1])
                    detection_masks_reframed = utils_ops.reframe_box_masks_to_image_masks(detection_masks,detection_boxes, image_np.shape[0], image_np.shape[1])
                    
                    detection_masks_reframed = tf.cast(tf.greater(detection_masks_reframed, 0.5), tf.uint8)
                    # Follow the convention by adding back the batch dimension
                    tensor_dict['detection_masks'] = tf.expand_dims(detection_masks_reframed, 0)

                image_tensor = tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')
                # Run inference
                output_dict = sess.run(tensor_dict,feed_dict={image_tensor: np.expand_dims(image_np, 0)})

                # all outputs are float32 numpy arrays, so convert types as appropriate
                output_dict['num_detections'] = int(output_dict['num_detections'][0])
                output_dict['detection_classes'] = output_dict['detection_classes'][0].astype(np.uint8)
                output_dict['detection_boxes'] = output_dict['detection_boxes'][0]
                output_dict['detection_scores'] = output_dict['detection_scores'][0]
                if 'detection_masks' in output_dict:
                    output_dict['detection_masks'] = output_dict['detection_masks'][0]

                # Visualization of the results of a detection.
                viz_utils.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
                    image_np,
                    output_dict['detection_boxes'],
                    output_dict['detection_classes'],
                    output_dict['detection_scores'],
                    category_index,
                    instance_masks=output_dict.get('detection_masks_reframed', None),
                    use_normalized_coordinates=True,
                    line_thickness=8)
```

**methord 2**

change first three line in the function  to: (run video loop inside the session)

```
    with detection_graph.as_default():
        with tf.Session() as sess:
            while cap.isOpened():
```

Do you know the reason for this, slow inference speed and apparent memory leak?

Are there any improvements I can make to the code to increase the inference speed?
(Other than using TensorFlow lite models)